# Cell overlaps and shows full content while editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, xcode6

I am using cells with two heights based on some status.

When start is **StatusAwarded** it shows full cell else it will show a part of it.

Here is the code to achieve this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SomeClass *someClass = dataArray[indexPath.row];
    if (someClass.status == StatusAwarded) {

        return 252.0f;
    }
    return 110.0f;
}
```

It works all fine but when it is in edit mode, it has this issue as shown below.

I am having effect like this while editing (Deleting).

[image]    [image]

**Question:**
Why is this happening? How to fix this?

Note: `Clip Subviews` is set to `YES`

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable `Clip Subviews` in Interface Builder / Storyboard.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're not reloading the other cells, try:

`[tableViewAdvancedBookings reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[indexPathsToExpand allObjects] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

instead of:

`[tableViewAdvancedBookings reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

which only reload the currect selected cell..
or maybe try reloading the whole table like:

`[tableView reloadData];`

and see what happen.. hope i've help, for some reason.. Good night, Cheers..